# android: poor quality of some markers on map

Tags: android, android-mapview, markers

i have a some trouble with markers on `mapview`.
I have 3 images (png) in each drawable folders (`ldpi`, `mdpi`, `hdpi`).
I initialize once marker drawable.
I have field `private Drawable drawable;` so i use it everywhere :

```
restaurantsOverlay = new SimpleItemizedOverlay(drawable, mapView);
...
restaurantsOverlay.addOverlay(overlayItem);
...
mapOverlays.add(restaurantsOverlay);
```

i have also override `draw` method in my class to hide the default shadow

```
@Override
    public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow, long when)
    {
        super.draw(canvas, mapView, false);
        return true;
    }
```

But a few markers have a bad quality and others are good. I can understand why.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something similar happens to me before. On the picture you provide you can see that the ugly markers have the shadow completly black. This is happening because there is more than one marker above the other. In my case it's because I have a loop that put the marker more than once in the map.

In your case I have to see the code, but I'm sure on 99% that this is the issue.